# For installing a new exterior light on a brick wall, can I connect the wires in a junction box mounted on the opposite side of the wall?

Tags: electrical, lighting

There is plenty of room to install the junction box on the other side of the wall and I would rather not put a box on the outside of the wall. Can I simply connect the wires in the junction box on the opposite side of the wall and mount the fixture to the brick wall?

Comment: It depends on the construction of the light. Please post an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as all the connections are inside the junction box you should be fine to do that.

Comment: Unshielded  wires running through a wall thickness into a fixture attached to a structural surface, not a box?